# Backbone.js: Collection.get() issues

Tags: backbone.js

Using Backbone.js, trying to do a simple get() on a collection after fetching items from server.

Fetch seems to work fine.  However, when I try to get an item by id from the collection, I'm getting the unexpected result of undefined, instead of a model.

Here's my backbone items code:

```
  Model.Scenario = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: function() {
      return {
        title: 'Scenario',
        answer: null,
      };
    }

  });

  Collection.Scenarios = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Model.Scenario,

    url: "data.php",


  });
```

Then the obj creation/fetch w/in a router method:

```
 var Router = new (Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
      ":id"    : "page",
      "" : "page"
    },

    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'page');
      this.scenarios = new Collection.Scenarios();
      this.scenarios.fetch();
      console.log(this.scenarios);
      console.log(this.scenarios.get(1));
      console.log(this.scenarios.get(2));

      Backbone.history.start();
    },

  }))();
```

Finally, here's what's logged to the debugger (so you can see the Collection is being populated):

```
child
  _byCid: Object
  _byId: Object
    1: child
    2: child
    3: child
    4: child
    7: child
    10: child
    11: child
    12: child
    13: child
    14: child
    15: child
    16: child
    17: child
    18: child
    19: child
    20: child
    21: child
    22: child
    23: child
    26: child
    27: child
    28: child
  __proto__: Object
  length: 22
  models: Array[22]
  __proto__: ctor

 undefined  //first call to get(id)
 undefined  //2nd call to get(id)
```

I'm stumped.  Sorry for the long post, but would appreciate any insight on what I'm missing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought is that the fetch() has not returned by the time you're doing your .get().

But, if what you posted is exactly what is happening, then the first console.log(this.scenarios) is showing that is IS loaded.

At any rate, you may want to try putting the console.logs into the success: event of the fetch, just to make sure that is not the issue.

My second thought is that the id for the models is not being set right.

Backbone.Model defaults to using the property "id" as the ID for a model, Collection.get(id) returns the model with the id you passed in.

So, does the response from data.php have an id property?

Try instead:

```
 var Router = new (Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
      ":id"    : "page",
      "" : "page"
    },

    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'page');
      this.scenarios = new Collection.Scenarios();
      this.scenarios.fetch({
        success: function(coll, resp) {
          console.log(coll);
          console.log(coll.first());
          console.log(coll.last());
        });
      Backbone.history.start();
    },

  }))();
```

Which should return the first and last model, and take the ID issue out of the picture.

If that works, what do the models show for the id property (coll.first().id)?

Comment: This seems to work, thanks.  As for the questions, yes, the data returned an 'id' property.  Also, the code above was copied directly from my script, so it indeed seemed to be a timing issue.  Greatly appreciated.